# pycharm не видит модули python-docx

Tags: python, pycharm, python-docx

Необходим был модуль для работы с документами, собственно выбор пал на `python-docx`, да и в принципе другого выбора то и нет. Установил `pip install python-docx` + `lxml` последней версии на всякий случай. `Python` использовал последний 3.5.10. Установил `python-docx` с 50 раза), так как постоянно `pycharm` то выдавал ошибки разные, то выдавал сообщение об успешной установке, но в папке с модулями нечего не было. В общем все установилось, `import docx` работает, pycharm его видит. Взял тестовый код из тех. документации:

```
self.document = docx.Document()
p = self.document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
self.document.save('demo.docx')
```

Инициализацию `docx.Document()` `pycharm` видит, но функции класса `Document()` не видит.
Давайте разбираться в чем проблема. Как видно на скрине, в папке с модулями для `pycharm`, все норм установлено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Едем дальше, посмотрим на какой класс ссылается `import docx`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим он ссылается на инициализацию всего `API`. Далее проверим, на что ссылается `docx.Document()`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, ссылается на класс `API.py` в котором есть функция инициализации `def Document()`, которая должна возвращать класс `document_part.document`, который судя по всему должен все таки вернуть класс `Document`, НО!!! нечего не возвращает.
Но если запустить данный код с предупреждениями, все отработает конечно же отлично! Как исправить проблемы в `pycharm`? Я пробовал `invalidateCaches`, переустановку `pycharm` и `python`, переустановку всех модулей и установку модулей вручную. p.s. `Pycharm` последней версии.

Comment: так питон в итоге 3.5 или 3.10?))) pycharm как и любая идлешка любит болеть, с этим ничего уж не поделать. питон переустанавливать тут смысла никакого нет, может помочь перебилдить скелетоны проекта(по сути - удалить `.idea` и открыть проект по новой), так же конечно же стоит удалить `venv` и по новой все туда поставить. если и это не помогает, то можно либо поменять версию пакета, либо же установить его прям руками - `.whl` в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, пересмотрев кучу видео на youtube и перерыв оф. сайт `pycharm` с подобными вопросами - итак, дело не в `pycharm` и даже не в `python`, дело в кривой `API` модуля `python-docx`. В общем подсказки по коду у вас не будут работать в любой `OS` и на любом редакторе, хоть `pycharm`, хоть `VS Studio`, хоть в стандартном `python IDE`. Исправлять этот баг разработчики `python-docx` не будут и вообще они проект уже давно забросили. Вариант только один - юзать код без подсказок.